# Return multiple select from different tables in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

Write the below stored procedure but only show the columns in the first select statement when add stored procedure to Crystal Report. I want make all select statements as a single select statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPublishedJobInfo]   
    @JobId INT,
    @EmployerId NVARCHAR(128)  
AS
    SELECT
        logoImage, 
        CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())  
    FROM 
        EmployerInfoes 
    WHERE
        id = @EmployerId  

SELECT 
    jobName, PublishedDate,  
    DATEDIFF(DD, DurationAvailableForApply, current_timestamp) 
       - CASE WHEN (MONTH(DurationAvailableForApply) > MONTH(current_timestamp)) OR (MONTH(DurationAvailableForApply) = MONTH(current_timestamp)  
AND DAY(DurationAvailableForApply) > DAY(current_timestamp)) 
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
          END   
FROM
    jobs 
WHERE 
    Id = @JobId  

SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM ApplyForJobs  
WHERE JobId = @JobId  

SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM JobViewNumbers  
WHERE JobId = @JobId  

SELECT 
    PersonalPhotoImage, firstName + middleName + lastName,
    phoneNumber, Email, gender, country   
FROM
    JobSeekerInfoes 
WHERE
    id = (SELECT UserId 
          FROM ApplyForJobs 
          WHERE JobId = @JobId)
```

Comment: Have you searched online? What did you find?

Comment: you want return multiple result set from your sp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crystal Reports using multiple results from a Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638384/crystal-reports-using-multiple-results-from-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: How i can return all select statements as single select to show columns names when create crystal report wizard .   Note \ no relationship between my tables .    Please Help me